# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Llevo unos días con este error y no sé a que se deba, estaba intentando hacer un login, con el make:auth de Laravel, la conexión a la base de datos la hace bien, los campos existen y las rutas funcionan correctamente, pero a la hora de autenticarse aparece este error:

```
ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 114: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTDOCS_PHP\Laravel_Dulius\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 378 and defined
```

por lo que he intentado hacer otro login a mano, pero me pasa exactamente lo mismo, si meto los datos incorrectamente me pone el mensaje que he puesto yo para mensaje incorrecto, pero si meto los datos bien me salta el mismo mensaje.
Estos son los datos del nuevo login

rutas

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('inicia','autenticandoController@inicioSession');
Route::post('loginx','autenticandoController@loginx');
```

controlador

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Auth;

class autenticandoController extends Controller
{

    public function inicioSession()
    {
        return View('inicioSession');
    }

    public function loginx(Request $request)
    {

        if(Auth::attempt(
                array(
                            'email'=>$request->email,
                            'password'=>$request->password,
                        )))
        {

            $respuesta = ' correo  '.$request->email;
            $respuesta += ' password '.$request->password;
            return  $respuesta;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'fallo login';
        }

    }

}
```

vista

```
@extends('layouts.appinicia')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Inicia Session</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/loginx') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Correo Electronico</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contraseña</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Recuerdame
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Iniciando Session
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Olvidaste tu password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

modelo User

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'apellido', 'tipo','email','password'
    ];

      public function getlistaNombreCompletoAttribute()
    {

        return $this->nombre.'  '.$this->apellido;
    }

    public function relacionPerfilesUsuario()
    {   
        return $this->hasOne('App\perfiles_usuario');
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($valor)
    {
        if(!empty($valor))
        {
         $this->attributes["password"]= bcrypt($valor);
        }
    }
}
```

este es el login personalizado, la vista es la misma que la de make:auth, salvo que he modificado algunas rutas y los nombres.
Como digo he probado en ambos casos por caminos diferentes y el resultado es el mismo.
¿Por que puede ser?

Comment: Por favor coloca el contenido de App\User ahi debe estar el problema

Comment: Ya lo he añadido

Comment: Ahora parece que funciona, la clave estaba en el User como decias, he añadido lo que ha comentado el compañero de abajo y ahora funciona
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente deberías tener algo así en tu `User` :

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {

    use Authenticatable;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: ¡¡¡¡¡ FUNCIONO !!!!!,  llevo probandolo durante dias y no he logrado hacerlo funcionar. Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta, ahora ya puedo continuar.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para aclarar un poco lo que sucedió, es que al realizar el login la clase internamente no consulta por una instancia de `App\User` sino por la interface `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`, es por eso que el código de más arriba solucionó el problema ya que está implementando dicha interface dentro del App\User. Por otro lado, hace uso de [Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Authenticatable.php), que es un trait que implementa los métodos de `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`. Espero haber aclarado un poco el por qué del error y el por qué de la solución ;)

Saludos.